# Binary reading and writing in C++

Tags: c++, microcontroller, sd-card

I am making an data logger project. In my data logger, I have 5 sensors like: temperature, humidity, accelerometer, light and barometer.

Here, I am storing the data in to SD card in binary format. I'm storing accelerometer @3200HZ and all other sensors at 1HZ.

While writing, I'm adding a special character to each measurements like below.

```
 if(DRDY)
  { 
    fwrite(&accdata,sizeof(char),1,logFile);  // accelerometer special char         
    accelerometer.getOutput(readings);
    int16_t store[3] = {(int16_t)readings[0],(int16_t)readings[1],(int16_t)readings[2]};  // accelerometer data
    fwrite((store),sizeof(int16_t),3,logFile);

   } 


    if(flag_humi)
  { 
    flag_humi = 0;
   fwrite(humidata,sizeof(char),1,logFile); // humidity character
   float store2[1] = {sht.readHumidity()};  // humidity data
   fwrite(store2,sizeof(float),1,logFile);
   }
    if(flag_temp)
  { 
   flag_temp = 0;
   fwrite(tempdata,sizeof(char),1,logFile);  // temp character
   float store1[1] = { sht.readTemp()};   // temp data
   fwrite(store1,sizeof(float),1,logFile);
  }
```

While reading, it separates the data according to the special character.

```
   while ((nr = fgetc(logFile)) != EOF){
       if (nr == 5){    // 5 is special character  for accelerometer
         fread(read,sizeof(int16_t),3,logFile);
          pc.printf("\r\n %i, %i, %i ",read[0],read[1],read[2]);
              }


    else if(nr == 10){  // 10 is char for temp
           fread(temp_read,sizeof(float),1,logFile); 
           pc.printf("\r\n %f",temp_read[0]);
                     }
    else  if(nr ==15)   // 15 is character for humidity
                    { 
          fread(humi_read,sizeof(float),1,logFile); 
          pc.printf("\r\n %f",humi_read[0]);
                   }
```

Everything is fine. Now I would like to remove a special character for the accelerometer since writing special character makes loss of some samples.

I tried once by writing accelerometer without spl.character and other sensors with spl.character.

While reading, I thought I could keep only else to read accelerometer since other have else if anyway.

```
   while ((nr = fgetc(logFile)) != EOF){
    if(nr == 10){  // 10 is char for temp
           fread(temp_read,sizeof(float),1,logFile); 
           pc.printf("\r\n %f",temp_read[0]);
                     }
    else  if(nr ==15)   // 15 is character for humidity
                    { 
          fread(humi_read,sizeof(float),1,logFile); 
          pc.printf("\r\n %f",humi_read[0]);
                   }
    else  {    // 5 is special character  for accelerometer
         fread(read,sizeof(int16_t),3,logFile);
          pc.printf("\r\n %i, %i, %i ",read[0],read[1],read[2]);
              }
```

But it is showing all wrong values and it is unstoppable. How can I achive this?

Comment: What is that special chatacter and how does it "make loss of some samples"?

Comment: I would recommend using serialization.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview

Serialization will help your code scale better and allow different languages to read it easily.

Comment: You are reading the first byte of the accelerometer data and then throwing it away when you read `3 * sizeof(int16_t)` which also reads the first byte of the next data.

Comment: In addition to what @Harvey says, the first byte of accelerometer reading may just happen to have 10 or 15 as the first byte, which would make your program mis-interpret the data as a different kind of reading. All in all, you likely want to keep the special tag in place. Now, what do you mean by *"writing special character makes loss of some samples"*? Maybe that's the problem you should be concentrating on.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: good catch. Also, Gandhi, why did you say this: "since writing [the accelerometer] special character makes loss of some samples?" How did it cause you to lose data? Is the timing so tight that you can't keep up with the sampling rate if you write one extra byte?

Comment: @Harvey . You are right. I am doing that mistake. I'm working on it. Thank you very much.

Comment: While writing accelerometer at 3200 HZ which is very high frequnecy writing again a special character at 3200 HZ may take time hence instead it writing up to 2700 samples only. That is the reson I'm thinking to remove that special character for accelerometer

Comment: How to read accurately the accelerometer data

Comment: @Gandhi: try buffering your sample writes. Write 4kiB (for example) of samples at a time. That might give you a speed boost. Are you reading and writing in the same thread? If so, split the reading and writing up into multiple threads. Good luck.